# scipy.io.wavfile.read returns data as a pair list of 1/0,1/0.. why?

Tags: python, scipy

The title basically explains the problem i'm having
the following is the code in question:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
import pdb

# Wav audio files in our directory, taken from Clinger's audio samples.
file1 = 'audio/wayfaring.wav'
file2 = 'audio/excerpt0.wav'

# Read() returns a tuple (sample rate, data read from array)
sample_rate2, stereo_data2 = wavfile.read(file2)
sample_rate1, stereo_data1 = wavfile.read(file1)

print sample_rate2
print sample_rate1

# Data is a list of tuple lists, representing stereo sound (left and right)
# Print out the first ten frequency samples
print stereo_data2
print stereo_data1

Output:
44100
44100
[[ 417  186]
 [ 440  179]
 [ 458  186]
 ..., 
 [1200 1020]
 [1143  921]
 [1079  820]]
[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

for some reason, wavfile.read works for file2 but not file1.

Comment: i also understand that wavfile.read does not support 24bit sample widths, what is a sample width? and how would I check to validate that my files are okay to feed into wavfile.read?

Comment: i did a wave.getsampwidth on both wav files and got back 2 for both

Comment: Are you sure the data is incorrect?

Comment: I wrote an alternative to `scipy.io.wavfile.read` here: https://gist.github.com/WarrenWeckesser/7461781  Does that return different data?

Comment: run `soxi` on both files, and post the outcome.

Comment: Pretty busy at work this week, will try asap, thanks for the feedback